# How do you unlock the 4 extra characters?

Tags: super-mario-party

In Super Mario Party, you have 4 extra characters that are locked at the beginning of the game.

Without a single player mode to speak of, how do you unlock them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The unlockable characters are

- **Donkey Kong**

  - Complete three different courses in River Survival.
- **Diddy Kong**

  - Complete Chestnut Forest (World 2) of Challenge Road.
- **Dry Bones**

  - Appears randomly after playing different modes.
- **Pom Pom**

  - Complete Salty Sea (World 5) of Challenge Road.

[source](https://www.mariowiki.com/Super_Mario_Party#Character_unlock_criteria)

Comment: rather odd that DK(pretty much a staple char since mp1) is a locked character... but ok.

Comment: Got to point out that doing these actions, you will need to speak to the character in the plaza before he/she is available to play.

Comment: So keep a look out for new characters. They always are just in front of the stage, behind the main board mode